# failed to resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha4

Tags: android, android-studio

I imported a project from my work-space. After this some errors were shown which I can't solve.

[image]

The message

> Install Repository and sync project

was shown as a link, but clicking on it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: add `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4` or `2.0.0` and do gradle

Comment: I have done before what you said but same error coming so please tell me some other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `constraintLayout` is not available yet on any stable relase of Android Studio. You have to download the [latest Android Studio Preview](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest)  to use it.

Comment: after updated new android studio again same error came so I change  compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha4' to  compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1' so new error came up like " No resource identifier found for attribute 'texttype' in package 'android' " and " Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe''finished with non-zero exit value 1"

Comment: Have you tried to download the latest support library ?

Comment: you're welcome, please valid my answer if it was useful

Answer (score 1):

Add `ConstraintLayout` to your project.

To use `ConstraintLayout` in your project, proceed as follows:

1. Ensure you have the "maven.google.com" repository declared in your
   module-level `build.gradle` file:

   ```
   repositories {
       maven {
           url 'https://maven.google.com'
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add the library as a dependency in the same `build.gradle` file:

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
   }
   ```
3. In the toolbar or sync notification, click Sync Project with Gradle Files.